# WebSphere MQ error MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED 2035 even with CHLAUTH(DISABLED)

Tags: windows, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect a Windows client application to a remote WebSphere MQ Manager in a test environment.

**Client**

- Windows 7 SP1 x64
- WebSphere MQ 7.5 Client

**Server (VM)**

- Windows 2008 R2
- WebSphere MQ 7.5 Server

Both machines are on the same domain.

The queue manager QM1 was created in WebSphere MQ Explorer (elevated to Administrator).

For test purposes, I am not interested in authentication, so I have disabled MQ authentication with ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64>runmqsc QM1
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2011.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager QM1.
display qmgr chlauth
     1 : display qmgr chlauth
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QM1)                             CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

However, despite disabling authentication I still get the 2035 error.

The AMQERR01.log for the QM shows:

```
03/06/2015 11:35:41 - Process(3520.657) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(MYSERVER) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.1) QMgr(QM1)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
```

I am running the client application as my domain user (elevated to Administrator). It's worth noting that this client code has been working in production environments for years and still does. It works in environments with and without MQ channel authentication configured, so I feel certain the issue is an environmental problem particular to my client or server machine.

Are there any other things that can cause 2035 MQ authentication error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the client side user ID is known on the server side machine. It is flowed from client to queue manager and used if you don't override it with anything else, e.g. CHLAUTH.

Comment: Thanks Morag, checking this by trying to explicitly add my user account as an administrator on the server revealed that although the server machine was on the same domain, there was something not quite right as I got a "The trust relationship between this workstation and primary domain failed". So I took the server out of the domain and put it back in again, and now it works fine.  To be clear to other readers, I did not need my user as a server administrator, I just used that as a way to check the user ID was known as Morag suggested.